# Review Request Schematic - LISN Design

Tags: pcb, rf, ltspice, emc, kicad

I need help with designing an LISN (Line Impedance Stabilization Network) for pre-compliance testing. This is my first big PCB project. It is not for sale, it will only be used at my job for testing before going to the lab.

I need the LISN to be designed with respect to CISPR 16 and FCC requirements.

[image: LISN Circuit FCC/CISPR16]

[image: Standard Impedance values]

I have performed simulations on LTspice in order to see the behaviour of my circuit.

**These are the output impedance simulations:**
[image]

[image]

**Next up I have my input side filtering**

[image]

[image]

**Lastly, I have my insertion loss simulations**

[image]

[image]

Finally I have a schematic design on KiCad, but I am not sure I am doing it correctly.

[image]

Comment: What about it did you want to review? Note that, if you're using stock simulation components, you won't have any modeling of component or layout parasitics. And without layout and BOM posted, we are unable to evaluate the same.

Comment: Hey @TimWilliams I used components from the database with parasitics. Okay I will work on the pcb and update this once I have it, does the sechematic make sense?

Comment: The output impedance test had an erroneous Generator_input_resistance resistor I think, but I'm not clear what you were modeling there. Anyway, Thevenin resistance on that node is just whatever is connected, and frequency response is straightforward being there are few elements on it.